# save upload file with date jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I wonder if i can upload file with date that I uploaded and save it in folder how can I do it ?

HTML code :

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <h1><span class="fui-upload"></span></h1>
        <h3>File Uploader</h3>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg upload-btn" type="button">Upload File</button>
        <input id="upload-input" type="file" name="uploads[]"></br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should do it server side so show your server upload code

Comment: how to do it with server side ?? and is there another way to do it without server side ??